# How to convert string to date format in java?

Tags: java, sql, date

How to convert string "Monday, 10 January 2017 | 04:58 PM" to a java.sql.Date 2017-01-10?

Comment: Stack Overflow has hundreds of Questions about parsing a String as a date-time. How do those not solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEEE, dd MMMMMMM yyyy | hh:mm a");
      Date parsed = format.parse("Monday, 10 January 2017 | 04:58 PM");
      java.sql.Date sql = new java.sql.Date(parsed.getTime());
    } catch (ParseException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```